# Can I filter an array in elastic?

Tags: elasticsearch

I had to insert a huge amount of data into elastic and I have done it in the following manner.
I need to query this object but I am unable to filter the "logData" array. Can someone help me out here ? is it even possible to filter an array in elastic?

```
"_source": {
  "FileName": "fileName.log"
  "logData": [
    {
       "LineNumber": 1,
       "Data": "data1"
    },
    {
       "LineNumber": 2,
       "Data": "Data2"
    },
    {
       "LineNumber": 3,
       "Data": "Data3"
    },
    {
       "LineNumber": 4,
       "Data": "Data4"
    },
    {
       "LineNumber": 5,
       "Data": "Data5"
    },
    {
       "LineNumber": 6,
       "Data": "Data6"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a way to query such that I get only few items from this array ?
like:

```
"_source": {
  "FileName": "fileName.log"
  "logData": [
    {
       "LineNumber": 1,
       "Data": "data1"
    },
    {
       "LineNumber": 2,
       "Data": "Data2"
    },
    {
       "LineNumber": 3,
       "Data": "Data3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [no dedicated](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html) array mapping type in ES.

With that being said, when you have an array of objects with shared keys, it's recommended that you use the [`nested` field type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) to preserve the connections of the individual sub-objects' attributes. If you don't use nested, the objects [will be flattened](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html#nested-arrays-flattening-objects) which may lead to *seemingly* wrong query results.

---

As to the actual query -- assuming your mapping looks something like this:

```
PUT logs_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "logData": {
        "type": "nested"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

you'll need to filter those `logData` sub-documents of interest, perhaps with a `terms_query`. Then and only then can you extract only those array objects that've matched this query (`lineNumber: 1 or 2 or 3`).

The technique for that is called `inner_hits`:

```
POST logs/_search
{
  "_source": ["FileName", "inner_hits.logData"],
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "logData",
      "query": {
        "terms": {
          "logData.LineNumber": [
            1,
            2,
            3
          ]
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61964178/8160318) for more info.

Comment: Hay! yes, this works. but I have "FileName": "fileName.log" also which is also a part of that filter. would it work if I have two queries in place ? I mean I need to filter based on "FileName": "fileName.log" and also based on logData.LineNumber

Comment: No problem -- just use a [nested `must` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html#nested-query-ex-query).